# Data Fetching Mern Stack

Tags: javascript, arrays, fetch, javascript-objects

I'm using React JS I just want to display the data on my website to show the user's order details. Only the productId is showing on the website but the name, description is not visible.

```
fetch(`https://secret-tundra-31885.herokuapp.com/users/${userId}/myOrder`, {
            headers: { 
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${user.accessToken}` 
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data =>{
        console.log(data);

        setMyOrders(data.order.map(orders=>{

            return (

                <tr key={orders._id}>
                <td>{orders._id}</td>    
                 <td>{orders.name}</td>  
                <td>{orders.description}</td>
                </tr>
                    
                        )

        }))
            
            })
```

Comment: Please share code in text format and not image so it's easier for anyone to copy.

Comment: noted sir. Thank you